# UILabel text with different font size and color

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Howto set different font size and color in a UILabel with Swift?

I need to color the first char of the string with different color and size than the rest of the string.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Suppose you want to have a smaller and gray currency symbol like this:

[image]

Just use a `NSMutableAttributedString` object:

```
let amountText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "€ 60,00")

// set the custom font and color for the 0,1 range in string
amountText.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12), 
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()],
                         range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
// if you want, you can add more attributes for different ranges calling .setAttributes many times

// set the attributed string to the UILabel object
myUILabel.attributedText = amountText
```

**Swift 5.3:**

```
let amountText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "€ 60,00")

// set the custom font and color for the 0,1 range in string
amountText.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
                              NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.gray],
                             range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
// if you want, you can add more attributes for different ranges calling .setAttributes many times
// set the attributed string to the UILabel object

// set the attributed string to the UILabel object
myUILabel.attributedText = amountText
```

Comment: It's just a [Self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: hello @lifeisfoo - this is not working

Comment: Hi @ParthDhorda this code works nicely for this case and other developers found it useful. Probably your use case is a little bit different and you need to ask a specific question for it.

Comment: hi @lifeisfoo then only change is I am using this inside the tableview, not only your answers but none of the answers from the stackover flow works for me

Comment: that's a further evidence that your problem needs a dedicated question on SO :)

Comment: I don't think this needs a dedicated question, as attributed text is gonna work same in label and inside the UITableView.